# Dependency Injector and choosing the a class at runtime

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

My simple application could, using dependency injection, log something **one way or the other way**. Each logger is a class, derived from an interface `ILogger`. The class `LoggerFactory` decides which logger to return to the fantasy application `TheAmazingApp` and then the application uses that concrete logger.

Question: how to implement this user choice, i.e. loading the proper class at run time using Autofac?

The console app below can be compiled. Observe the comment in "LoggerFactory" if you will (last class/file) - reiterating my challenge.

**Main.cs**

```
using Autofac;

namespace DepInjection
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var Builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            //Start configure
            Builder.RegisterType<TheAmazingApp>();
            Builder.RegisterType<LoggerFactory>();
            Builder.RegisterType<NormalLogger>().As<ILogger>();
            Builder.RegisterType<VerboseLogger>().As<ILogger>();
            //End configure

            var Container = Builder.Build();

            using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                scope.Resolve<TheAmazingApp>().AmazeUs();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**TheAmazingApp.cs**

```
namespace DepInjection
{
    public class TheAmazingApp
    {
        private ILogger _logger;
        public TheAmazingApp()
        {
            _logger = LoggerFactory.GetLogger();
        }

        public void AmazeUs() => _logger.Logger();
    }
}
```

**ILogger.cs**

```
namespace DepInjection
{
    public interface ILogger
    {
        public void Logger();
    }
}
```

**VerboseLogger.cs**

```
namespace DepInjection
{
    public class VerboseLogger : ILogger
    {
        public void Logger() => 
            Console.WriteLine("Verbose Log");
    }
}
```

**NormalLogger.cs**

```
namespace DepInjection
{
    public class NormalLogger : ILogger
    {
        public void Logger() => 
            Console.WriteLine("Normal Log");
    }
}
```

**LoggerFactory.cs**

```
namespace DepInjection
{
    public class LoggerFactory
    {
        private static string? _choice;
        public static ILogger GetLogger()
        {
            //emulates the result of a user choice at run time
            _choice = "other";

            //...but how do I implement this using a dependency injector?
            return _choice == "1" ? new NormalLogger() : 
                new VerboseLogger();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: DI is not designed to be manipulated by user input, it is basically sugar to avoid explicit dependency declaration. It has "scope" though, but it is not common to use them other than describing web endpoint operation and short lived dependencies used inside. For user input use function signature (add argument to GetLogger), for dependency junctions use DI. Factory can get access to DI container to decide what to return (antipattern alert).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to solve this, but one of the most convenient methods is to create a proxy logger implementation that makes the choice, e.g.:

```cs
public class UserChoiceLogger : ILogger // This is your proxy
{
    private readonly NormalLogger normal;
    private readonly VerboseLogger verbose;

    public UserChoiceLogger(NormalLogger normal, VerboseLogger verbose)
    {
        this.normal = normal;
        this.verbose = verbose;
    }

    public void Logger()
    {
        //emulates the result of a user choice at run time
        _choice = "other";

        if (_choice == "1")
            normal.Logger();
        else
            verbose.Logger();
    }
}
```

Where you change `TheAmazingApp` to simply use constructor injection:

```cs
public class TheAmazingApp
{
    private ILogger logger;

    public TheAmazingApp(ILogger logger)
        {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void AmazeUs() => logger.Logger();
}
```

This can be registered as follows:

```cs
var Builder = new ContainerBuilder();

//Start configure
Builder.RegisterType<TheAmazingApp>();
Builder.RegisterType<NormalLogger>();
Builder.RegisterType<VerboseLogger>();
Builder.RegisterType<UserChoiceLogger>().As<ILogger>();
//End configure

var Container = Builder.Build();

using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    scope.Resolve<TheAmazingApp>().AmazeUs();
}
```

Notice how the need to have a factory deminished. Factories are [often redundant](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/abstract-factories/).

Comment: This looks dangerous to me:     "public UserChoiceLogger(NormalLogger normal, VerboseLogger verbose)".  Now it's only two types of loggers, next time it's in some game with 50 types of swords. Or a File Exporter leaving you with a choice of 10 types of file formats to choose from. I bet you see where this is going. Secondly, it appears to me that this constructor "guarantees" me that both objects are instantiated, when I only need one.

Comment: There's nothing dangerous about this. But if you require a dynamic set of loggers (which you didn't specify in your question) the solution with two hard-coded dependencies isn't suited.

Answer (score 0):

After study it appears that the named and keyed services could provide an answer.Something like...

```
container.ResolveNamed<NormalLogger>("Normal") //"Normal" is returned via user input
```

...is possible and this gives options. Using an explicit keyed method would resemble this:

```
container.ResolveKeyed<NormalLogger>(Logger.Normal) //Logger.Normal is returned via user input
```

Haven't figured out a pretty way for the totality of the code, so I can't use this. But it's a step in the right direction. And like user @eocron mentioned, a Dep. Injector isn't really cut out for this task.

Comment: hello, if you plan to use Keyed to resolve the service, see the answer on this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76749014/autofac-wheninjectinto-like-grace-ninject)