# Autofac WhenInjectInto like Grace/Ninject

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, autofac, ioc-container

i have this implementation with Grace (it's the same in Ninject) but i need use then in Autofac but autofac does not have a "WhenInjectInto" functionality. How can i migrate this code? Thx

```
public interface ILocationRepository
{
    Task<Location?> GetByIDAsync(int id);
}

public class LocationRepositoryProxyCache : BaseProxyCache, ILocationRepository
{
    private readonly ICacheProvider<Location> _cacheProvider;

    private readonly ILocationRepository _locationRepository;

    public LocationRepositoryProxyCache(ICacheProvider<Location> cacheProvider, ILocationRepository locationRepository)
    {
        _cacheProvider = cacheProvider;
        _locationRepository = locationRepository;
    }
    public Task<Location?> GetByIDAsync(int id)
    {
        return _cacheProvider.GetOrSetAsync("CACHE_KEY", () => _locationRepository.GetByIDAsync(id));
    }
}

public class LocationRepository : BaseRepository<Location>, ILocationRepository
{
    public LocationRepository(IMyInterface myAppDb) : base(myAppDb) { }

    public Task<Location?> GetByIDAsync(int id)
    {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

Grace code to migrate to Autofac

```
registrationBlock.Export<LocationRepository>().As<ILocationRepository>().When.InjectedInto<LocationRepositoryProxyCache>();
registrationBlock.Export<LocationRepositoryProxyCache>().As<ILocationRepository>();
```

Comment: I don't know about Ninject (never used it); but it seems some kind of [decorator](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html#decorators) with a [conditional registration](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#conditional-registration), isn't it? I think it could be solved combining `RegisterDecorator` plus an `OnlyIf` in the registration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [here](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html#resolving-with-attributes)
, I made the sample code to register the Service by Keyed

```
        builder.RegisterType<LocationRepository>().Keyed<ILocationRepository>(SourceType.Fetching);
        builder.RegisterType<LocationRepositoryProxyCache>().Keyed<ILocationRepository>(SourceType.Caching);
         
        builder.RegisterType<Consumer>().As<IConsumer>().WithAttributeFiltering();
```

Here is the LocationRepository and LocationRepositoryProxyCache

```
public class Consumer : IConsumer
{
    private ILocationRepository cacheRepo;
    private ILocationRepository fetchRepo;
    public Consumer([KeyFilter(SourceType.Fetching)] ILocationRepository fetchService ,
        [KeyFilter(SourceType.Caching)] ILocationRepository cacheService)
    {
        cacheRepo = cacheService;
        fetchRepo = fetchService;
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        cacheRepo.GetByIDAsync(1);
        fetchRepo.GetByIDAsync(2);
    }
}
public interface IConsumer {
    void Test();
}
```

I hope, it can help you.